# How to remove parent commits from a child branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-flow

I had a parent branch and a child branch created from the parent branch. After merging the parent branch to the master, the branch was deleted. I've made some more changes in child branch and when I created the pull request, I can see the commits of the parent branch in the child branch. How can I change the starting commit of the child branch?

To be more clear, the following depicts the current situation and I wish to remove `P1` and `P2` from the commits shown when trying to create a PR from `child_branch` to `master`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to rebase `child_branch` on top of `master` :

```
# from child_branch :
git checkout child_branch

# run :
git rebase master
```

`git` will spot that all commits up to `P2` are already part of `master`, and will replay one by one the commits in the range `P2..child_branch`